# Deserialize XML file with objects to Array

Tags: c#, arraylist, deserialization

This is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;

namespace Opgaver
{
     class OpgaveController
    {
        static ArrayList _arrAktiveOpgaver = new ArrayList();
        public ArrayList arrAktiveOpgaver
        {
            get { return _arrAktiveOpgaver; }
            set { _arrAktiveOpgaver = value; }
        }

        static ArrayList _arrAfsluttedeOpgaver = new ArrayList();
        public ArrayList arrAfsluttedeOpgaver
        {
            get { return _arrAfsluttedeOpgaver; }
            set { _arrAfsluttedeOpgaver = value; }
        }

        static int _opgavenr = 100;
        public int opgavenr
        {
            get { return _opgavenr; }
            set { _opgavenr = value; }
        }

        public void opretOpgave(string opgavenavn, string opgavebeskrivelse, int opgaveprioritet, DateTime opgaveafsluttetdato)
        {
            DateTime oprettetdato = new DateTime();
            oprettetdato = DateTime.Now;
            bool opgaveafsluttet = false;
            Opgave opgave = new Opgave(oprettetdato, _opgavenr, opgavenavn, opgavebeskrivelse, opgaveprioritet, opgaveafsluttet, opgaveafsluttetdato);

            if (opgave.opgaveAfsluttet == false)
            {
                _arrAktiveOpgaver.Add(opgave);
            }
            else
            {
                _arrAfsluttedeOpgaver.Add(opgave);
            }

            _opgavenr++;
        }

        public OpgaveController()
        {

        }



        }

        public void test()
        { 
            string outfile = @"C:\Folder\Tester.xml";

            XmlSerializer xs;

            Serialize<List<Opgave>>(arrAktiveOpgaver, outfile);
            arrAktiveOpgaver = <List<Opgave>>(outfile);//deserialize data - Generates this error: Error 2   Using the generic type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<T>' requires 1 type arguments   P:\Programmerings opgaver\Opgaver\Opgaver\OpgaveController.cs   107 33  Opgaver

        }

        private void Serialize<T1>(ArrayList arrAktiveOpgaver, string outfile)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string inputFile)
        {
            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            T deserializedObject = default(T);

            using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
            {
                deserializedObject = (T)s.Deserialize(textReader);
                textReader.Close();
            }

            return deserializedObject;
        }

        public static void SerializeToXml<T>(T objToSerialize, string outputFile)
        {

            XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());

            using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
            {
                s.Serialize(textWriter, objToSerialize);
                textWriter.Close();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

i need to serialize the arraylist, and deserialize it..

and here is my opgave class:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Opgaver
{
    [Serializable()] public class Opgave : IComparable
    {
        DateTime _oprettetDato = new DateTime();
        public DateTime oprettetDato
        {
            get { return _oprettetDato; }
            set { _oprettetDato = value; }
        }

        int _opgavenr;
        public int opgavenr
        {
            get { return _opgavenr; }
            set { _opgavenr = value; }
        }

        string _opgaveNavn;
        public string opgaveNavn
        {
            get { return _opgaveNavn; }
            set { _opgaveNavn = value; }
        }

        string _opgaveBeskrivelse;
        public string opgaveBeskrivelse
        {
            get { return _opgaveBeskrivelse; }
            set { _opgaveBeskrivelse = value; }
        }

        int _opgavePrioritet;
        public int opgavePrioritet
        {
            get { return _opgavePrioritet; }
            set { _opgavePrioritet = value; }
        }

        bool _opgaveAfsluttet = false;
        public bool opgaveAfsluttet
        {
            get { return _opgaveAfsluttet; }
            set { _opgaveAfsluttet = value; }
        }

        DateTime _opgaveAfsluttetDato = new DateTime();
        public DateTime opgaveAfsluttetDato
        {
            get { return _opgaveAfsluttetDato; }
            set { _opgaveAfsluttetDato = value; }
        }

        public Opgave()
        {
        }

        public Opgave(DateTime oprettetdato, int opgavenr, string opgavenavn, string opgavebeskrivelse, int opgaveprioritet, bool opgaveafsluttet, DateTime opgaveafsluttetdato)
        {
            _oprettetDato = oprettetdato;
            _opgavenr = opgavenr;
            _opgaveNavn = opgavenavn;
            _opgaveBeskrivelse = opgavebeskrivelse;
            _opgavePrioritet = opgaveprioritet;
            _opgaveAfsluttet = opgaveafsluttet;
            _opgaveAfsluttetDato = opgaveafsluttetdato;
        }

        //Sorterings metode
        public int CompareTo(object obj)
        {
            Opgave Compare = (Opgave)obj;
            int result = this.opgavenr.CompareTo(Compare.opgavenr);
            if (result == 0)
                result = this.opgavenr.CompareTo(Compare.opgavenr);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That isn't a valid xml document. An xml file can have only one root element. It could be an xml *fragment*, but few things work with fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this static methods whenver you want to serialize or deserialize data:
example:

```
public void test()
{ 
    string outfile = @"C:\Folder\Tester.xml";

    SerializeToXml<List<Opgaver>>(arrAktiveOpgaver, outfile);//serialize data

    arrAktiveOpgaver = DeserializeFromXml<List<Opgaver>>(outfile);//deserialize data
}

public static T DeserializeFromXml<T>(string inputFile)
{
    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T deserializedObject = default(T);

    using (TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(inputFile))
    {
        deserializedObject = (T)s.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();
    }

    return deserializedObject;
}

public static void SerializeToXml<T>(T objToSerialize, string outputFile)
{

    XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType());

    using (TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(outputFile))
    {
        s.Serialize(textWriter, objToSerialize);
        textWriter.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marc: Sorry but I didn't get your point. I made them generic and static so he can use them for any ordinary xml serializaion and deserialization. for instance if her wrap the `List<Opgave>` In a serializable class, he can still use this static methods...

Comment: hmm Thx for the code Jalal..
but im getting this error:
Using the generic type 'system.collections.gerneric.list<t> requires 1 type arguments

Comment: @Mathias: Did you pass a `Opgave` to the `List<>` so it should be `List<Opgave>`, Just copy the code I putted in the `test()` method and try it.

Comment: yeah ive copied the code.. the only thing that missed it a ";" after the serialize line.. but im still getting the error..

Comment: is it becuase im using an arraylist?

Comment: @Mathias: Yes, just replace `List<Opgave>` with `ArrayList`, I updated the code in the answer.

Comment: okay.. just another error: 
"The name 'Serialize' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Mathias: change the `Serialize<ArrayList>` to `SerializeToXml<ArrayList>`, I corrected the code.

Comment: i got it.. i just corrected the method from SerializeToXml to Serialize.. just had to wake up i think..

Comment: @Mathias: great, don't forget to mark this answer as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it answers your question right, so others will know that it helps you ;)

Comment: okay now im getting this error when generating the xml file:
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type Opgaver.Opgave was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically

Comment: Mark your `Opgave` with `[Serializable]` attribute so it can serialized correctly so:    `[Serializable()]public class Opgave { .... }`

Comment: okay.. so i'll just need to put that infront of my opgave class?

Comment: @Mathias: Yes, that is correct. whenever you want to serialize a class, your class should be decorated with the `[SerializableAttribute]`.

Comment: okay.. hmm strange it still generates an error.. look at my code at the top I've added the Opgave Class

Comment: @Mathias: It should not. try to rebuild your solution "press Alt + B + R".

Comment: hmm i just did that.. and it diden't work.. is there anyway that i can send you my solution? - if you want to see the whole thing..

Comment: @Mathias: Ok I tested your code. however the problems seems to be because of the `ArrayList`. I don't know why you are using it anyway. I would use `List<Opgave>` instead. so the code should be: 
            static List<Opgave> _arrAktiveOpgaver = new List<Opgave>();
            public List<Opgave> arrAktiveOpgaver
            {
                get { return _arrAktiveOpgaver; }
                set { _arrAktiveOpgaver = value; }
            } //Also replace the ArrayList in List<opgave> when use serialize or deserialize methods.

Comment: damn! thats perfect!! superb! thanks a lot! it works 100 % now!
the reason why i used the Arraylist instead of list is becuase I've learned that in the schools.. but ive gotta use List instead from now on Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Serialize array of `Opgave` instead of serializing them in loop.

```
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(arrAktiveOpgaver.GetType());
xs.Serialize(sw, arrAktiveOpgaver);
```

And then deserialize as array of `Opgave`.

Comment: i chaged the serializer to this:

        public void test()
        { 
            string outfile = @"C:\Folder\Tester.xml";
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(outfile);
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(arrAktiveOpgaver.GetType());
            xs.Serialize(sw, arrAktiveOpgaver);
            sw.Close();
         }
but then i get this error : System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type Opgaver.Opgave was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types

Comment: @Mathias what *exactly* is the type of `arrAktiveOpgaver` ?

Comment: @Mathias, Maybe this question would be helpful; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988737/web-services-xmlinclude-in-a-derived-class-instead-of-a-base-class

Comment: arrAktiveOpgaver is an ArrayList

Comment: @Mathias, Update your question with source code, sow we can reproduce you issue.