# wse3 inherited class type not accepted as method parameter

Tags: parameter-passing, wse, inherited

I will try to describe my problem.
I have a method in a proxy class(auto-generated by wsdl) that accepts as its first argument an object of Type BaseType.I try to pass an inherited type and i get

> The type xyz was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically

After searching for a lot of time i read about namespacing and about the xmlinclude attribute.So initially i had

> /// 
>       [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "2.0.50727.3038")]
>       [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
>       [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
>       [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="esDatabaseServersSoap", Namespace="http://smbsaas/foo/bar")]
>       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(SomeOtherType))]
>  
>       public partial class esDatabaseServers : Microsoft.Web.Services3.WebServicesClientProtocol {
>                private System.Threading.SendOrPostCallback GetRawSqlDatabasesPagedOperationCompleted;
>   ................................................
>   ................................................
>   public int AddSqlDatabase(**BaseClass** item, string groupName) {

and then i tried to add

> [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="esDatabaseServersSoap", Namespace="http://smbsaas/foo/bar")]
>       [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(SomeOtherType))]
>    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIncludeAttribute(typeof(**MyInheritedType**))] 
>    ***i added this line***
>       public partial class esDatabaseServers :

i got

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified type was not recognized: name='MyInheritedType', namespace="http://smbsaas/foo/bar", at .

MyInheritedType inherits from baseClass.

I really don't know what to do.Any ideas please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting XmlInclude attributes to the base class - as mentioned in this post: [Web services - XmlInclude in a derived class instead of a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988737/web-services-xmlinclude-in-a-derived-class-instead-of-a-base-class)

However this would be useful only if you own webservice.

If it is just for some enhancements (which may not be your case), you can try out using partial classes.